# Does Simperium store/maintain data on their server?

Tags: simperium

It might sound a silly question, but as the FAQ on http://simperium.com/faq/ did not help with required information, I am asking it here.

We plan to make us of Simperium for our project, but our concern is that the data should not be stored or maintained by any other server other than ours. FYI, on http://simperium.com/faq/ they say that we can host our own Simperium library but also state that it would allow us to m MIRROR our data, so can anybody help me resolve a confusion as would Simperium guys keep a watch on our data or simply sync and ignore that ?

Any help/guidance/reference would be appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simperium stores the data you sync in a datacenter: backups and sysops tasks are done for you. We use Simperium to power up the Mac/iOS App 'Simplenote': your app's information is kept confidential and safe.

Hope that helps!

Comment: No problem!. If there's anything else we could help you with, please, just say the word!.